# Recursively drawing squares in Python

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics

I am having trouble recursively drawing squares. My question is what length should be passed to my draw_squares function when I recursively call it. I cant seem to get it to fit correctly within the original square. Find example of output attached. [Output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZzhG.png)

```
draw_squares(side_size, depth):
    turtle.forward(side_size)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(side_size)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(side_size)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(side_size)
    turtle.left(90)
    if depth > 1:
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(side_size * 1 / 2)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.pendown()
    else:
        pass

#Draw diagonal squares within original square

def draw_squares2(side_size, depth):
    if depth > 1 and depth % 2 == 0:
        turtle.right(45)
        draw_squares(side_size * 1/3, depth - 1)
```

Comment: Some [basic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagorassConstant.html) [knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square#Other_facts) about geometry might help.

Comment: You will need to use [this function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.sqrt).

Answer (score 2):

First, you're not drawing squares *recursively* here: draw_squares2 calls only draw_squares, which never calls itself or its parent.  A recursive function calls itself, either directly or indirectly.  It looks like you're working toward a recursive solution (moving the turtle to the middle of one side), but you're not there yet.

Among other things, I note that the picture you linked to your posting doesn't seem to match the code above.  Still ...

The problem you have is, as others have pointed out, basic geometry: what is the side length of a square inscribed in another square at a 45-degree angle?  The length you need is **sqrt(2) / 2** times the length of the parents square's side.

Keep track of how you use this value; your program is susceptible to multiplying and dividing things by 2.  Consider using **print** statements at critical points to trace your computations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as posed isn't recursive, but it could be.  I wrote an example approach below using *stamping* which, while not directly translatable to your *drawing* approach, should give you ideas but not a solution:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

colors = ["navy", "gold"]

STAMP_UNIT = 20

def draw_figure(turtle, side_size, depth):
    turtle.turtlesize(side_size / STAMP_UNIT)
    turtle.color(colors[depth % 2], "white")
    turtle.stamp()

    if depth < 1:
        return

    turtle.forward(side_size / 4)

    turtle.left(45)
    draw_figure(turtle, side_size / 2 / 2**0.5, depth - 1)
    turtle.right(45)

    turtle.backward(side_size / 2)

    turtle.left(45)
    draw_figure(turtle, side_size / 2 / 2**0.5, depth - 1)
    turtle.right(45)

    turtle.forward(side_size / 4)  # return to starting point

yertle = Turtle(shape="square", visible=False)
yertle.penup()

draw_figure(yertle, 240, 3)

screen = Screen()

screen.exitonclick()
```

At depth 3 we get:

[image]

But setting the depth to 1 gets us the original figure in question:

[image]